# WP7 Localization issues from C#

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, windows-phone-7.1

I'm having an issue with the localization in my converters. So, I tried a new project and still have problems.

So, I created a fresh new Silverlight for Windows Phone application (7.0, but 7.1 don't resolve my problem).

I added two resources files: Strings.resx and Strings.fr.resx. This two files have two string property: HelloString and ByeString, all initiated correctly.

Then, I go to the Mainpage.xaml.cs, in the ctor and add the following simple line.

```
PageTitle.Text = Strings.HelloString;
```

Whenever I have the emulator or my phone set to English or French, I always got the same strings (Hello).

I tried to rename the file Strings.fr-FR.resx. Still the same issue.
The CurrentUICulture returned from the current thread is correct.
I also tried to force culture on the resource:

```
Strings.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't say that you've set the `SupportedCultures` for the project. Without this the additional language resource files will never be used.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941931(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: This is the end of my 2-hr search.